# Time trigger not running on function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a function that I want to run on a time trigger every hour (in the test I have put it to minutes). However, it is not running unless I manually trigger it. Can anyone help me?

```
function setTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("LiDCOcheck")
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(1)
    .create();
}

function LiDCOcheck() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var buttons = ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO;
  var bed = ss.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var due = new Date(ss.getRange("D2").getValue());
  var time = new Date(ss.getRange("A2").getValue());

  if (+due.getHours() == +time.getHours()) {
    var lidco = ui.alert("It hsa been 24 hours since the LiDCO in Bed " + bed + " was calibrated.  Is it still required?", buttons);
    if (lidco == ui.Button.YES) {
      ss.getRange("D2").setBackground('#ff9900');}
    else {
      ss.getRange("D2").setValue('Not Required')}
  }
}
```

[image: Execution Transcript]
[Test page](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gwKoifSaZ9DqafXUSvqNTT3MwaJnSaGyV070iOZG6sU/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Instead of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`, try explicitly opening the spreadsheet with `SpreadsheetApp.openById()`.

Comment: @Diego, I have tried that but the timer trigger still doesn't work.

Comment: When you say it isn't running, do you actually mean it doesn't execute, or it doesn't do anything when it does execute? If your if test is false, there are no changes made.

Comment: @tehhowch Sorry I mean it doesn't execute at all when it is on a time trigger. It will work correctly when I manually trigger it.

Comment: @tehhowch I noticed the syntax error and corrected it. I have tried both manual and programmatically. When the Google app trigger didn't work I tried to program it. Neither are working correctly.

Comment: @AidanWilson post your execution transcript. Odds are you cannot bind to the UI class from a time based trigger, because there is no UI in the instance that runs the function.

Comment: @tehhowch I have added a picture of the execution transcript. As a novice to this i don't actually understand what it means so i have also added a link to the sheet.

Comment: A script can only interact with the UI for the current instance of an open editor, and only if the script is container-bound to the editor. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script My hunch is your script is not container-bound. Worth a look at least.

Comment: @JeremyKahan It is container-bound, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Okay, I hope someone gives you a good answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SpreadsheetApp.getUi() cannot be called from this context"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117119/spreadsheetapp-getui-cannot-be-called-from-this-context)