# Call showSidebar() from a cell in google spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

As user **Serge insas** answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36117264/6568725),

> Ui Dialogs can not be called by time triggered functions, they have to be triggered by a user action, that's to say a click on a menu item or some sort of button that calls the function showing the UI.

What about calling *showSidebar()* or *showModalDialog()* from a cell? Something like the following formula, which should open the sidebar automatically when the value in A1 is greater than 0:

```
=if(A1>0;showSidebar();"nothing to show")
```

Is this possible?

This is my script:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu().addItem('Open Beeper', 'openBig').addToUi();
}

function openBig() {
  var htmlContent = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('audioHtml').setTitle('Beeper');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlContent);
}
```

I can open the sidebar by clicking the item in the addons menu without problems but when I call *openBig()* from a cell I get the following error:

> Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.

What am I doing wrong? What is missing?

Comment: Not possible. Custom functions have much less permissions/authority than time triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TheMaster is right. You are doing nothing wrong. Simply, you cannot call `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` from the sheet itself (any cell). It is only allowed to be called from the context of the menu.

Comment: It works fine with a onEdit trigger. However if the onChange (automate) trigger is used, it sends the context error.

Comment: That's because the onEdit() trigger only occurs on user edits.

Comment: Some people have been using the onEdit trigger to run functions from the mobile versions of Google Sheets.