# How to detect user changing sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to detect and trigger custom action during opening specific sheet in spreadsheet?

I could not find proper function in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: The tags you chose are not appropriate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Related [How do I make a Sidebar display values from cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30628894/1595451)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do polling as Mogsdad suggested you could use this code in your Sidebar (or any UI element)

```
$(function() {
   /**
   * On document load, assign click handlers to each button and try to load the
   * user's origin and destination language preferences if previously set.
   */
   poll();
}

function poll(interval){
    interval = interval || 2000;
    setTimeout(function(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadSheetName)
        .withFailureHandler(showError).getSheetName();
    poll();
    }, interval);
};

function loadSheetName(sheetName) {
   alert(sheetName);
   }

function getSheetName() {
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadSheetName)
        .withFailureHandler(showError).getSheetName();
   }
```

And in your .gs code

```
function getSheetName() {
var sheetName =         SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
return sheetName;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome and was giving me a hint of what i am exactly was looking for. However. it has some syntax errors in it, therefor here my corrected code from above:

`$(function(){
  poll();
});

function poll(interval){
  interval = interval || 2000;
  setTimeout(function(){
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(loadSheetName)
      .withFailureHandler(showError)
      .getSheetName();
    poll();
  }, interval);
};

function loadSheetName(sheetName) {
  alert(sheetName);
}

function showError(error) {
  alert(error);
}`

Comment: @LJay this code was working back in 2016. If there were changes since there, please append the current answer with your code or add a separate answer with current api calls

Answer (score 2):

There is no API provided to trigger on user events, aside from the ones in the documentation you've linked.

I can think of only one work-around: If your application involves having a custom UI element, specifically a sidebar or dialog, then you could poll for the active cell, and determine the active sheet from that.

See [How to poll a Google Doc from an add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773177/how-to-poll-a-google-doc-from-an-add-on/24773178#24773178) for a start.