# On cell selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am learning to use google app script. I have written code to get row number in which so far I succeeded but can't find a way to assign it to a cell or row change event trigger. Can someone help me figure out how to do this?
My code is as follows :

```
function onChange(event) {  
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  
var currentCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();  

sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(currentCell.getRow());  
}
```

Comment: There's no trigger available that fires `onSelect`.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "onSelect" trigger on Google Apps Script but you could use the poll technique. Basically, you will have to use a sidebar to hold client-side code that will check for the selected cell every determined time. For code examples checkout the following Q/A

- [How do I make a Sidebar display values from cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30628894/1595451)
- [How to detect user changing sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37703309/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the trigger? `onChange` triggers need to be explicitly hooked up because they're considered [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) (opposed to [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/), which just require saving the .gs file).

You can manage your triggers from the Menu in your Apps Script Editor:
[image: Edit > Current project's triggers]

Comment: Actually the event should trigger on selecting any cell, not on change, I realized it searching web, but still not sure of onSelection is simple or installable.

Comment: To my knowledge, there’s no trigger for OnSelection at this time, but I hope you found a workaround for what you were trying to do!