# Use variable value from .gs file in custom HTML sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a google sheet where I have scripted a custom sidebar.

Within the sidebar, I want to display the value of column I within the active row.

I've managed to work out the script to store the variable 'I' when the sidebar is opened:

```
var hotelName = ""

function openSidebar() {
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s=ss.getSheetByName("Contract Registry Document");
var row=s.getActiveCell().getRow();
var column=9;
hotelName = s.getRange(row, column).getValue();
Logger.log(hotelName);
}
```

However I now need this to appear in an empty DIV element in my sidebar. How do I export this variable?

UPDATE:

That works great. I've now added as well a button to the sidebar to refresh and what I want that to do is to update the script so that if the user has changed rows, the new hotel name will show. At the moment I've added this HTML:

```
 <div id="footer">

 <div><?= hotel ?></div>

 <p><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" id="testing"></i></p>

 </div>
```

And this JQuery to the index file:

```
$("#testing").on('click', function buttonClick() {
google.script.run.buttonClick();
});
```

And for the function I just copied the original function:

```
function buttonClick() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s=ss.getSheetByName("Contract Registry Document");
var row=s.getActiveCell().getRow();
var column=9;
var hotelName = s.getRange(row, column).getValue();

// get the html template after retrieving the values
var html_template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');

// set the value for the index.html `hotel` placeholder/scriptlet
html_template.hotel = hotelName;

// evaluate the template
var sidebar_html = html_template.evaluate();

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(sidebar_html);

Logger.log(hotelName);
}
```

However, really I want the value of the cell to update asynchronously so that the sidebar doesn't re-load, just the hotel name...

Would this be possible??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a Sidebar display values from cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628894/how-do-i-make-a-sidebar-display-values-from-cells)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Getting data from a spreadsheet on loading a sidebar

Don't forget to select the row first before displaying the sidebar.

code.gs

```
function openThisSideBar()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('hotel').setTitle('MySideBar');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function getHotel()
{
  var s=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Contract Registry Document");
  var row=s.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var n=Utilities.formatString('Your Hotel is named: %s',s.getRange(row, 9).getValue());
  return n;
}

function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('MyTools')
    .addItem('Open Sidebar', 'openThisSideBar')
    .addToUi();
}
```

hotel.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function()
    {
       google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(updateHotel)
           .getHotel();
    });
    function updateHotel(name)
    {
       document.getElementById('hotel').innerHTML=name;
    }
    console.log('MyCode');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="hotel"></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

You can add your refresh like this:

```
<script>
function refresh()
    {
       google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateHotel)
          .getHotel();
    }
</script>
```

And the new html:

```
<input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="refresh();" />
```

> That way you needn't refresh the entire page but just the div.

Comment: Cheers for this. The main code is working great. But I cannot get the refresh function up and running. Can I check where you are inserting the refresh function? I've tried it in the .gs file as well as within a script tag in the HTML and the refresh doesn't seem to be working. Thanks

Comment: I had a semicolon after the withSuccessHandler.  I think it will work now.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets) with [createTemplateFromFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createTemplateFromFile(String)) and [evaluate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template#evaluate()). Then use the [printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets) in the html file and set their value in your `openSidebar()`

```
function openSidebar() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Contract Registry Document");
  var row=s.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var column=9;
  var hotelName = s.getRange(row, column).getValue();

  // get the html template after retrieving the values
  var html_template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');

  // set the value for the index.html `hotel` placeholder/scriptlet
  html_template.hotel = hotelName;

  // evaluate the template
  var sidebar_html = html_template.evaluate();

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(sidebar_html);

  Logger.log(hotelName);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>The hotel name is: <?= hotel ?></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for this - I implemented and it works great!! How could I add a refresh function so that the div containing the hotel name is updated, not the rest of the sidebar?

Comment: for that, you want to use @Copper's jQuery solution..this one was just for your original question about exporting a variable to an html sidebar