# App script gmail add-on programmatically close compose window

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm developing a gmail add-on, it has a composeTrigger which opens my gmail add-on. Inside the app, there is a button allows user to click and send the draft in compose dialog.

Everything works great except for after sending email successfully, there seems to be no way to programmatically close the compose window. It confuses the user as they might click send again.

Was there any workaround to  programmatically close compose window from app script?

I went through official docs but haven't found anything useful

```
const drafts = GmailApp.getDrafts()

drafts[0].send()

// Now I want to close the compose email window in gmail
```

Comment: Hey! Would you be able to provide a sample of the code that you are working on, so that we can check further?

Comment: @MicTest sample code is added

Comment: The ultimate question is how to programmatically close compose window from App script

Comment: Thank you for providing your sample code. Upon running it, it seems that even without the compose window open, the script is able to pull up the email draft and send it. If it's alright to ask, may I know if: 1) the button that the users click pulls up the compose window (or needs to pull up the compose window), and 2) the logic of running the script to send the draft. Since the compose window is already open, wouldn't it be fine to just send the email normally?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61107677/7215091

Answer (score 0):

you couldn't programmatically close the compose UI (Compose window) in Gmail using Google Apps Script or Gmail Add-ons. This limitation was due to security and user experience concerns to prevent unauthorized interference with a user's email composition.

Typically, a user is responsible for closing the Compose window manually. If you want to provide functionality in your Gmail Add-on that requires specific actions after a user finishes composing an email, you could guide the user to perform those actions, but you cannot automatically close the Compose window.