# How to deal with Access-Control-Allow-Origin for myDrive files

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, cors

The question arises from this note:

> Someone here suggested using div's. The HTML requirement is very
>   skeletal. The 3D display is basically canvas, but it requires seven
>   three.js files, ten js files of my own making to exchange parameters
>   and other variables with the global variable and .dae collada files
>   for each of the 3D models you can see. If they could be linked in like
>   jQuery that might be the solution but I wonder about conflicts.

on [Questions on extending GAS spreadsheet usefulness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425029/questions-on-extending-gas-spreadsheet-usefulness)

principally, *if they can be linked like jQuery* part

The files to be linked are on myDrive. The thinking is that if I can copy the files into GAS editor, it seems as secure and more flexible to bring them into the html directly.

code.gs

```
function sendUrls(){   
   var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("___Blazer").next();
   var sub = folder.getFoldersByName("assembler").next();
   var contents = sub.getFiles();
   var file;
   var data = []
    while(contents.hasNext()) {
       file = contents.next();
       type = file.getName().split(".")[1];
       url = file.getUrl();
       data.push([type,url]);
     }
     return data;
}
```

html

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (files) {
    $.each(files,function(i,v){
       if(v[0] === "js"){
           $.get(v[1])
       }
    })
})
.sendUrls();
```

[image: console]

The first url opens the proper script file but the origin file is not recognisable to me.

Comment: Why not get it directly from server and pass the blob to client?

Comment: @TheMaster In the current stage, the blob cannot be directly passed from Google side to HTML using ``google.script.run()``. So if the data is the binary data and text data, pass the base64 encoded data and the string data, respectively. Or directly retrieves the data from client side using ``fetch()``. At that time, for example, you can use OAuth2, Service Account and API key. And also, if you use ``google.script.run``, the access token can be also retrieved from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is a proper answer as it relies on cors-anywhere, viz:

```
function importFile(name){
  var myUrl = 'http://glasier.hk/cors/tba.html';
  var proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
  var finalURL = proxy + myUrl;
  $.get(finalURL,function(data) {
     $("body").append(data);
     importNset();
  })
}

function importNset(){
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function (code) {
    path = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/"+code;
    $.get(path)
    .done((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
      nset = data;
      cfig = nset.cfig;
      start();
      })
    })
  .sendCode();
}

var nset,cfig;
$(document).ready(function(){
  importFile();
});
```

but it works, albeit on my machine, using my own website as the resource.

I used the Gas function [in gas Shop](http://glasier.hk/blazer/gasShop.html) to make the eight previously tested js files into the single tba.html script only file. I swapped the workshop specific script files for those needed for google.script.run but otherwise that was it. If I could find out how to cors-enable my site, I think I might be able to demonstrate how scripts might be imported to generate different views from the same TBA and spreadsheet interfaces.