# Update web app drop down lists daily with new items

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I’ve got a functioning google webapp that draws data from a Google spreadsheet. I’d like to use the same webapp link over the course of a week, but have the drop down lists update daily with new items. Currently the drop down lists are created in my .gs file when the web app is first deployed. Is it possible to either update these lists on the fly as new data comes available or is there a way to re-deploy the webapp say overnight to update the lists that way?

So far have searched for 'updating html lists in google webapp on the fly' and similar.

Below have included the .gs and html so you can see how the list is sourced and how it is used in HTML.

```js
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/idcode/edit#gid=0";


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Draws");
  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 8).getValues();

function doGet(e){
  
  var m_list =ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow()).getValues();
  var m_htmlListArray = m_list.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');

  var f_list =ws.getRange(1, 5, ws.getRange("E1").getDataRegion().getLastRow()).getValues();
  var f_htmlListArray = f_list.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');


  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
  tmp.title = "Title";
  tmp.mlist = m_htmlListArray;
  tmp.flist = f_htmlListArray;
  var html = tmp.evaluate().setTitle('Team Selection WebApp');
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html); 
  htmlOutput.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');  
  return htmlOutput
```

```html
<select class="form-select form-select-sm" id="m_p1" onchange="getDrawNumOne()">
              <option selected>Men's Player 1</option>
              <?!= mlist; ?>
            </select>
```

Comment: Possible, but probably requires some significant rewrite of the code

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Yes it's possible to update the lists on the fly, actually there are several ways to do this, this depends on the source of the list items and other factors. Please add more details and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thanks Rubén - have had a go at that above. Not looking for the exact code - very happy to receive some high level ideas and then I can go off an explore. So challenge for me is - if the 'Draws' sheet is updated with new lists...how can I get that new list picked up in the already deployed webapp dropdown.

Comment: Thanks everyone - used setInterval in my HTML script which is now working nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the values for the dropdown comes from the spreadsheet, you might make use of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) on the client-side to implement a polling solution.

## Related

### JavaScript

- [Using setInterval() to do simplistic continuous polling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8682622/1595451)

### Google Apps Script && Client-Side JavaScript

- [How do I make a Sidebar display values from cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30628894/1595451)
- [Update value in a spreadsheet sidebar when next row is selected in table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58621104/1595451)